# Chosen Module working on one <select> but not other selects

Tags: 8

I use drupal 8 and chosen module and I set "Minimum number of options for single select" and "Minimum number of options for multi select" and "Minimum number to show Search on Single Select" to "always apply" .
Now I create advanced searche with views and use 2 filter criteria whit entity refrenced exposed.
When I set one of them setting to dropdown and other to autocomplete , it worke correctly . But when I set all of them settings to dropdown chosen not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set above code in theme.libraries.yml and it worked .

```
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery.once
```